# Access из столбца в строку

Tags: sql, запрос, access, ms-access

Есть две таблицы:

1. отдел | ФИО | табельный номер | дата
2. ФИО | табельный номер | дата | время

Столбцы ФИО | табельный номер | дата имеют одинаковые значения (берутся из разных источников, но совпадают)
В одну дату во второй таблице может быть несколько строк с разным временем (до 5 строк, не больше).

Возможно ли сделать третью таблицу вида:
отдел | ФИО | табельный номер | дата | время1 | время2 | время3 | время4 | время5

Если значений "время" меньше 5, то заполнить можно нулём или прочерком.

Например:

бухг. | Иванов | 123 | 19.02.2023 | 10:35 | 14:00 | 19:30 | - | -

VBA использовать технически нет возможности (на работе, ограничения безопасности, спасибо, что access оставили), только стандартные запросы access 2016 или SQL

Спасибо))

Comment: Вот вообще не вижу проблем - обычный перекрёстный запрос. Всё, что надо сделать - это пронумеровать записи в группе, что в Аксе хоть и нетривиально, но несложно.

Comment: Не до конца расписал(( Итоговая таблица вида:
отдел | ФИО | табельный номер | дата | время1 | время2 | время3 | время4 | время5 - это "шапка"
бухг.  | Иванов | 123 | 19.02.2023 | 10:35 | 14:00 | 19:30 | - | -

Comment: Да это всё и так понятно, без объяснений. И вообще ни на что не влияет.

Comment: Для меня влияет)) А что Вы подразумеваете под нумерацией записей в группе?

Answer (score 0):

Помогли в другом месте, 
столбцы (Букг - таблица-источник данных):

```
время1: DMin("[Время]";"[Букг]";"[Отдел]='" & [Отдел] & "' And [ФИО]='" & [ФИО] & "' And [ТабНомер]=" & [ТабНомер] & " And [Дата]=#" & Format([Дата];"dd/mm/yyyy") & "# And [Время]=#" & Nz([МинВр];CDate("23:59:59")) & "#")
время2: DMin("[Время]";"[Букг]";"[Отдел]='" & [Отдел] & "' And [ФИО]='" & [ФИО] & "' And [ТабНомер]=" & [ТабНомер] & " And [Дата]=#" & Format([Дата];"dd/mm/yyyy") & "# And [Время]>#" & Nz([Время1];CDate("23:59:59")) & "#")
время3: DMin("[Время]";"[Букг]";"[Отдел]='" & [Отдел] & "' And [ФИО]='" & [ФИО] & "' And [ТабНомер]=" & [ТабНомер] & " And [Дата]=#" & Format([Дата];"dd/mm/yyyy") & "# And [Время]>#" & Nz([Время2];CDate("23:59:59")) & "#")
время4: DMin("[Время]";"[Букг]";"[Отдел]='" & [Отдел] & "' And [ФИО]='" & [ФИО] & "' And [ТабНомер]=" & [ТабНомер] & " And [Дата]=#" & Format([Дата];"dd/mm/yyyy") & "# And [Время]>#" & Nz([Время3];CDate("23:59:59")) & "#")
время5: DMin("[Время]";"[Букг]";"[Отдел]='" & [Отдел] & "' And [ФИО]='" & [ФИО] & "' And [ТабНомер]=" & [ТабНомер] & " And [Дата]=#" & Format([Дата];"dd/mm/yyyy") & "# And [Время]>#" & Nz([Время4];CDate("23:59:59")) & "#")
```